# Deploy microservice (spring boot app) on Openshift via Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, microservices, openshift, devops

I need to deploy a spring boot app (**docker image**) in openshift via jenkins, to achieve this I am doing the below steps,

1. I created the docker image of spring boot app using the jenkins pipeline 'freestyle' template -
2. pushed that docker image in '**Artifactory**' registory

The above two steps are completed and working, But I am struggling to deploy that docker image (which is in Artifactory registory) to **openshift** server via **jenkins pipeline**,
It seems like its a common requirement but I did not find any good documentation on this, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Last time I used openshift it was version 3.x and it had image streams. Also I used openshift client tool "oc" to update deployments.

Comment: @DmitriyTarasevich you have deployed via jenkins pipeline?

Comment: Yes, jenkins was deployed to openshift and configured to run pipelines in openshift. So I used oc in jenkinsfile.

Comment: In my case I need to use Jenkins which is not deployed in openshift, It is configured externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few solutions ranging depending on your level of commitment and level of automation DevOps integration wanted:

1. fast and dirty solution - If you insert the `oc` command line tool into your Jenkins agents\slaves (usually best if you ran on machines or VMs), you can create an environment variable to hold the application name and as long as you created it with `oc new-app` or similar you can execute `oc import-image` followed by the ImageStream name nad it will check the docker repo tag for changes in the version hash (and if the hash changed it will update it). check [here](http://dumbitdude.com/inject-password-in-jenkins/) for basic token injecting to avoid password spills through git.

example Jenkinsfile snippet:

```
pipeline {
    agent { 'jenkins_slave_vm' }
    environment {
        SERVICE='myapp'
    }

    stages {
        stage('build&push') {
            steps {
                sh "docker build -t myrepo/${SERVICE}:latest -f Dockerfile.production ."
                sh "docker push myrepo/${SERVICE}:latest"
            }
        }
        stage('deploy') {
            steps {
                sh "oc login --token=${OC_IMAGE_UPDATE_TOKEN}"
                sh "oc import-image ${SERVICE}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. more robust enterprise solution - using the k8s\openshift plugin (different plugins) for Jenkins, the general k8s plugin is used to spin up pods with the environment needed (like node for frontend applications), bring back down at the end of usage, run the build stages while building the docker\container images with openshift BuildConfig object and basing the behavior on either `Dockerfile` configuration, `S2I` or fully managed by openshift using the `pipeline` method (though more complex and very platform invested compared to the other two), [here's](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/builds/understanding-image-builds.html) a fairly latest explanation for openshift 4.6 though existed since version 3.x as well. This method allows for a more declarative, reproducible, and in the long term consistent build strategy and is the one we at my current organization are currently using for the resource-saving and the consistency that originally came with the rise of containers.

[pipeline examples](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/building-declarative-pipelines-openshift-dsl-plugin)

3. halfway - trigger an openshift build with a webhook from the SCM platform (can check this out [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/triggering_builds.html)). removes some of the relience from Jenkins (and personally not tested) but if you really can't make it with the other options this might be the last straw.

Comment: Hi Noam, Thanks for answer and links, It seems the link https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/builds/understanding-image-builds.html is not working, could please update the working link.

Comment: Wow! That a first the openshift DNS record just doesn't work, when I search for the docs and try different links from Google none of them work, maybe try again later?

Comment: Just checked it, now it works!

Comment: yeah the link is working now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no code snippet from your side that I could extend to give you a copy paster solution, however, the easiest way to deploy to Kubernetes using Jenkins is the exact same way as one would do for other CI/CD tools as well, simply execute a `kubeactl apply` within the pipeline.

To do so you should have a folder called `k8s` (or similar) within your repository that contains all necessary files for the deployment process:

```
stackoverflow-repo
├── docker
│   └── Dockerfile
├── Jenkinsfile
├── k8s
│   ├── configmap.yaml
│   └── deployment.yaml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        ├── main.java
        └── resources
            └── app.properties
```

For security reasons it would be appropriate to [create a ServiceAccount or User in Kubernetes and assign it roles that are necessary for deployment (i.e. updating, patching and creating Services, Deployments and so on) using RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/).

There is also the option of using the [Kubernetes plugin for Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/), however, it is more complicated to use and results in a vendor lock which I would try to avoid, especially since Jenkins is somewhat on a path of extinction (compared to other CI/CD tools that are simpler, faster and more efficient in what they offer).

Keep in mind that many modern Kubernetes architectures [deploy via ArgoCD](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

[image]

The reason this is preferred is because it uses an approach called [GitOps](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/devops/what-is-gitops) and can easily be combined with any CI/CD tool, making it more easy to switch around since ArgoCD is doing the actually deployment. Furthermore it also offers a nice UI that gives clear and understandable information to people that are not used to working with Kubernetes on a daily basis.

Having said all that it is totally up to you what path you want to take but keep in mind that a simple `kubectl apply -f k8s/` inside your Jenkinsfile will accomplish excactly what you want and only requires you to place a [kubeconfig file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/) somewhere the running pipeline can access it (you can specify the path by doing something like `kubectl --kubeconfig /path/to/kubeconfig apply -f k8s/`).

Comment: Does kubernete is really needed to deploy the docker image in openshift?